# How to add a third dimension in MDX?

Tags: reporting-services, mdx

I have this `MDX` that shows the measures  for specific Ad Name in the last 4 months:

```
WITH 
  SET [Selected Measures] AS 
    {
      [Measures].[Cost]
     ,[Measures].[Clicks]
    } 
SELECT 
  [Selected Measures] ON COLUMNS
 ,NonEmpty
  (
    (
      [Ad Name Dim].[Ad Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS
     ,
        ClosingPeriod
        (
          [Time Dim].[Time Dim].[Month]
         ,[Time Dim].[Time Dim].[All Time]
        ).Lag(3)
      : 
        ClosingPeriod
        (
          [Time Dim].[Time Dim].[Month]
         ,[Time Dim].[Time Dim].[All Time]
        )
    )
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [CubeName];
```

And I would like to add another field that would be available to me in SSRS report, that will show the **first date that the specific ad had data on**

Something like **Min([Time Dim].[Time Dim].[Day]).**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested - if you can translate to a script against the AdvWorks cube then it's easier for contributors:

```
WITH 
  SET [Selected Measures] AS 
    {
      [Measures].[Cost]
     ,[Measures].[Clicks]
    } 
  MEMBER [Measures].[MinDate] AS 
    Head
    (
      NonEmpty
      (
        [Time Dim].[Time Dim].[Month] //<<to return minimum month but could be changed to a different level
       ,(
          [Selected Measures]
         ,[Ad Name Dim].[Ad Name].CurrentMember
        )
      )
     ,1
    ).Item(0).Item(0).Member_Caption 
SELECT 
  {
    [Selected Measures]
   ,[Measures].[MinDate]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,NonEmpty
  (
    (
      [Ad Name Dim].[Ad Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS
     ,
        ClosingPeriod
        (
          [Time Dim].[Time Dim].[Month]
         ,[Time Dim].[Time Dim].[All Time]
        ).Lag(3)
      : 
        ClosingPeriod
        (
          [Time Dim].[Time Dim].[Month]
         ,[Time Dim].[Time Dim].[All Time]
        )
    )
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [CubeName];
```

Comment: Thanks! this help for me! Have you got any solution for me if I want to use the "member_key" for displaying the  [Ad Name Dim].[Ad Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS? to display the ad's unique ID instead of it's name ?

Comment: Please can you post this as another question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26614958/in-mdx-what-is-the-best-way-to-display-the-member-key-of-all-dimension-members 

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

How about this(NOT TESTED):

```
With SET [Selected Measures] AS { [Measures].[Cost]
                            ,[Measures].[Clicks]  } 

SET SetOfMonths as ClosingPeriod([Time Dim].[Time Dim].[Month], 
[Time Dim].[Time Dim].[All Time]).Lag(3):ClosingPeriod([Time Dim].[Time Dim].[Month])

SET FirstDay as
HEAD([Time Dim].[Time Dim].[Day], 1)

SELECT  [Selected Measures]  ON COLUMNS,
nonempty(([Ad Name Dim].[Ad Name].[Name].allmembers,
SetOfMonths, FirstDay,     
[Time Dim].[Time Dim].[All Time])) ON ROWS
FROM [CubeName]
```